# MySQL: Sum if rows are equal

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, equals

I want to make a SQL select-query to select everything, but when the `client`, `thickness` and `material` are the same their value of 'amount' should be added.

How would I go about creating such a query?

[image: data sample]

Comment: give the sample data

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: @MZeinstra The OP's last edit showed the input and desired output. Your edit just has the input, why did you remove the output?

Comment: if client + material + thickness are the same i want to remove this duplicate but remind the amount and add this to the one wich doesnt get removed.

Comment: @Barmar I'm very sorry.. I didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly. You could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    client, 
    thickness,
    material,
    SUM(amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM
    Table1
GROUP BY
    client, 
    thickness,
    material
```

Comment: @Barmar : It was just an educated guess ;)

Comment: I thought he wanted something like `IF(client = thickness and thickness = material, amount, 0)`

Comment: @Barmar : Could be yes. We have to see what the op says

Comment: He posted an example, but someone edited it away. You were correct.

Comment: @Stefan : No problem. In the future to avoid confusion please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

if same column then

```
SELECT
   SUM(amount) AS Total
FROM
    Tablename
GROUP BY
    client, 
    thickness,
    material
```

Comment: How is this any different from my answer?